# Casting Nexus5 Screen to a smart TV without extra hardware

Tags: nexus-5, smart-tv

I was wondering if there is any way to cast my Nexus 5 screen on to my Samsung Smart TV without any additional hardware such as chromecast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your smart TV supports the Miracast protocol for wireless displays, then you can cast to it just the same way you would a Chromecast.

Comment: how to check if it supports it or not, btw here is the TV http://www.samsung.com/ie/consumer/tv-audio-video/television/led-tv/UE32F5500AKXXU

Comment: If the spec doesn't say it supports it, it probably doesn't.

Comment: i used to play movies on it through the "throw screen" feature of Movies app of my Xperia phone, also through my laptop wirelessly using AllShare.. well i guess i'll have to dig it up more to find out what can be done.

Answer (score 0):

In that case the answer would be you can try casting the nexus screen with the help of the Wi-Fi direct which I am sure is supported with the Samsung Smart TV.